# C++ static member variable of nested class in template class

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, static-variables

I made a template class **Block** and wanted to cache some data for each instance type of **Block**. For this reason I created an inner class **Cache** which is storing and initialising the data often used by **Block** class instances. But the compiler (Visual Studio 2017, C++17) is not accepting the static member variable definition and the error message is not helping me. Whats wrong with my code and how I can accomplish my goal?

**Errors:**
*Error  C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Cache'*

**Warnings:**
*Warning    C4346   'Cache': dependent name is not a type*

```
template<int D>
class Block
{
private:
    class Cache
    {
    public:
        int mData[D];
    public:
        Cache();
    };
private:
    static Cache mCache;
public:
    Block();
};

template<int D>
Block<D>::Cache Block<D>::mCache; // Syntax error "Cache"!

template<int D>
inline Block<D>::Block()
{
    // Use cache data.
    cout << Block<D>::mCache.mData[0] << endl;
}

template<int D>
inline Block<D>::Cache::Cache()
{
    // Initialise cache data.
    mData[0] = D;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `typename`

```
template<int D>
typename Block<D>::Cache Block<D>::mCache;
```

---

You can read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name, but put it short, compiler don't know if it's a type.